# How to write an algorithm that count the duration of time without repetitions

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, date, date-difference

We have an array of date interval arrays:
`[[start_date, end_date], [], ...]`
For example:

```
    [ 
      [01.02.2020, 01.05.2020], # 3 months
      [01.01.2020, 01.10.2020], # 9 month, but we cant count the time already in the array, so 6 month
      ...
    ]
```

As a result of executing the algorithm, we should get the number of days/months/years of the duration of the period.
How do i write this? I'll be grateful for your help

Comment: An easy approach is to decompose the intervals to individual days and remove all duplicates. A more sophisticated one is to combine all overlapping intervals and calculate the duration based on start / end difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the number of days the task can be solved quite easily:

- convert the input to an array of sets of dates (through `Range`)
- calculate sets union

So:

```
input = [["01.02.2020", "01.05.2020"],["01.01.2020", "01.10.2020"]]

days =
  input
    .map { |start_date, end_date| Date.parse(start_date)..Date.parse(end_date) }
    .map(&:to_set)
    .reduce(&:union)
```

(can be done more concisely; leaving this for you)

This gives you an accurate number of days (`days.size`), without duplicates lying in the ranges' intersections. But getting to month/years is a bit more tricky. Ok, maybe not tricky per se, but it needs some extra clarification on how to calculate partially covered months/years (for example, is it ok or not to calculate last 2 weeks of August and first 2 weeks of September as 1 month). For the simplest case it may be as simple as dividing days by 30 to get months and by 360 to get years (but the rules might be way more sophisticated).

Comment: Note that you could change `map(&:to_set)` to `map(&:to_a)`, or simpler, remove that line and change the preceding one to `map { |start_date, end_date| [*(Date.parse(start_date)..Date.parse(end_date))] }`. One could alternative write `days = input..map { |start_date, end_date| [*(Date.parse(start_date)..Date.parse(end_date))] }.flatten.uniq`, then `.count`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something on this general order:

- Convert each date to `time_t`.
- Sort those.
- Grab the first and last (earliest and most recent).
- Subtract to get a difference.
- Convert the result back to days/months/years.

Comment: what if i have this array:
`[[01.01.2020, 01.05.2020], [01.01.2022, 01.05.2022]]`
answer with your solution - 2 years 4 months, but correct answer is 8 months

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are given the following ranges.

```
ranges = ['01.02.2020'..'04.05.2020', '18.07.2020'..'12.08.2020',
          '14.09.2020'..'29.10.2020', '21.03.2020'..'21.06.2020',
          '07.02.2020'..'14.06.2020', '02.07.2020'..'12.07.2020']
```

---

The first step is to convert these to ranges of date objects.

```
require 'date'
```

```
arr = ranges.map { |r| Date.parse(r.begin)..Date.parse(r.end) }
  #=> [#<Date: 2020-02-01 ((2458881j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..#<Date: 2020-05-04 ((2458974j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-07-18 ((2459049j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..#<Date: 2020-08-12 ((2459074j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-09-14 ((2459107j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..#<Date: 2020-10-29 ((2459152j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-03-21 ((2458930j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..#<Date: 2020-06-21 ((2459022j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-02-07 ((2458887j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..#<Date: 2020-06-14 ((2459015j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-07-02 ((2459033j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..#<Date: 2020-07-12 ((2459043j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

---

Next determine the earliest and latest date covered by these ranges.

```
earliest = arr.min_by { |r| r.begin }.begin
  #=> #<Date: 2020-02-01 ((2458881j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

```
latest   = arr.max_by { |r| r.end }.end
  #=> #<Date: 2020-10-29 ((2459152j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

---

Now create an array containing `latest - earliest + 1` elements with all elements initialized to `false`:

```
covered = Array.new(latest - earliest + 1, false)
  #=> [false, false,..., false]
covered.size
  #=> 272
```

After each range `arr[i]` has been considered `covered[d]` will equal `true` if any of the ranges in `arr` covers the date `earliest + d`.

---

We may now compute the desired results.

```
arr.each { |r| r.each { |d| covered[d-earliest] = true } }
```

```
covered.count { |e| e }
  #=> 225
```

---

Note that

```
covered.filter_map.with_index { |d,i| (earliest+i) if d }
  #=> [#<Date: 2020-02-01 ((2458881j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-02-02 ((2458882j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 
  #     ...
  #    #<Date: 2020-06-21 ((2459022j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
  #    #<Date: 2020-07-02 ((2459033j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    ...
  #    #<Date: 2020-07-12 ((2459043j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-07-18 ((2459049j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    ...
  #    #<Date: 2020-08-12 ((2459074j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-09-14 ((2459107j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
  #    ...                                                     
  #    #<Date: 2020-10-29 ((2459152j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

```
(Date.parse('2020-06-21') - Date.parse('2020-02-01') + 1 +
(Date.parse('2020-07-12') - Date.parse('2020-07-02')) + 1 +
(Date.parse('2020-08-12') - Date.parse('2020-07-18')) + 1 +
(Date.parse('2020-10-29') - Date.parse('2020-09-14')) + 1).to_i    
  #=> 225
```

Also,

`covered.count { |e| e }` is equivalent to `covered.count { |e| e == true }` and can alternatively be written `covered.count(&:itself)`.